# Postfix with smtp authentication failing

Tags: debian, php, postfix, smtp

I'm currently in the process of updating my new server to do the same tasks as my original older server (new server is running ***Debian wheezy***, old server is running ***Debian squeeze***).

The issue I'm having is sending email with pear using the following code:

```
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host'     => 'localhost',
                                     'port'     => '25',
                                     'auth'     => true,
                                     'username' => 'linuxUser',
                                     'password' => 'linuxPassword'));

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $text);
```

I am able to send emails from the terminal with

```
$mail example@email.com
```

However when I attempt to run the php script to send an email via pear I get an error in my mail.log

***mail.log Error***

```
postfix/smtpd[7835]: warning: SASL authentication failure: unable to canonify user 
and get auxprops
postfix/smtpd[7835]: warning: localhost[::1] SASL DIGEST-MD5 authentication failed: 
authentication failure
```

I'll outline a few of the config files that I've changed

***/etc/postfix/main.cf***

```
# SMTP Authentication
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtp_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks,
check_relay_domains, reject_unauth_destination

...     

smtpd_banner = mail.$mydomain ESMTP $mail_name  
mydomain = domain.com                           
myorigin = $mydomain                    
myhostname = mail.domain.com    
inet_interfaces = all
```

***/etc/default/saslauthd***

```
START=yes
MECHANISMS="shadow"
OPTIONS="-c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd"
```

***/etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf***

```
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
```

I initially thought that the SASL username & password hadn't been set correctly - most online tutorials show the username & password being stored in a separate DB file. However in my case the user name & password is assigned to a linux username/password.

I've no idea why this is not working, is this a postfix/SMTP error or pear/php error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed the following configuration file

***/etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf***

```
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN
```

This now allows authentication to work correctly.